# How to know when the root view controller of a navigation controller is going to be loaded?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, segue

I need to pass an object to the root view controller of an `UINavigationController` before it appears. I have its `root view controller` relationship set in `storyboard`, and it seems that I can't handle it like the other types of segues.

How could I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could assign the **UINavigationController** a **delegate** and implement the method -

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
      willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                    animated:(BOOL)animated {
     // check viewController is kind of class, check any flags

     // pass object to vc

}
```